# Tweet button with dynamic text and events

Tags: twitter, tweets, webintents

I want to have an `input` field in my page and a button so that the user can manually enter the tweet text and then when he its the submit button, the actual twitter status submit will open with the text the user entered.
moreover, I also want to get a callback when a user submit the tweet on twitter like [Web Intents Javascript Events](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events)

as far as I know there are 2 ways to do that:

1. re-render the tweet button after every change of the input using `twttr.widgets.load();`, something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chris27/DQw5b/4/) example, only instead of the update button use the `onchange` event of the input. **the problem** is when the tweet button is re-rendered its disappears for a moment.
2. the next option is not to use the twitter button, instead when the user hits submit open a new window and redirect to https://twitter.com/share with the tweet text as the query param (like twitter suggest in [Build Your Own Tweet Button](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button)). **the problem** with this solution is that I dont get an event when the user submit the tweet on twitter.

Any ideas how I can combine both requirements, dynamically change the tweet text & getting an event on tweet submit?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work, but my first thought is to use the tweet button, and add an invisible div over it which will capture the user's click, reload the widget with the user's text, and trigger a click on the widget 250ms later (or however long it might take it to reload on a slow device). You'll only get one flicker, so it wouldn't look smooth, but it wouldn't look like a bug either.